# Adding more parameters in ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am using AJAX function. I am passing 3 variables to the next page using AJAX. When I add the 4th variable the function doesn't get called.

```
Code:
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            //Browser Support Code
            function ajaxFunction(){
                var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

                try{
                    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
                    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } catch (e){
                    // Internet Explorer Browsers
                    try{
                        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                    } catch (e) {
                        try{
                            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        } catch (e){
                            // Something went wrong
                            alert("Your browser broke!");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
                ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){

                        var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
                        ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                    }
                }


             var count = document.getElementById('count').value;
             var type = document.getElementById('type').value;
             var sem = document.getElementById('sem').value;
              var rid = document.getElementById('room').value;


          ajaxRequest.open("GET", "add_requi_ajax.php?count=" + count+"&type="+ type+"&sem="+sem+"&rid="+rid, true);

        ajaxRequest.send(null);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using already debugged and well documented java-script framework like [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)?

Comment: We would need to see the values in the variables as well.

Comment: You should also use tools for debugging and troubleshooting of the ajax calls, like `Firebug` under FF

Comment: i dnt kno jquery.. and all values are integer

Comment: and the function works with 3 variables

Comment: why don't you try post method.

Comment: using this function req form is generated based on count.. So i need ajax..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is syntactically and logically correct, which means that the problem is likely one of your input IDs is wrong (typo? Should `room` be `rid`?), or you call the function before the inputs are rendered on the page (use `window.onload`).

Verify each of your input IDs. If they all look correct, then comment them out and hard code the values to rule out your inputs as a problem. Watch the error console for any error messages. If an uncaught error is encountered, it can *appear* that the function isn't being called.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to urlencode your values.

Comment: but the function is not getting called